# Error cargar datos dentro de Mongodb con body-parser

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy creando una app sencilla con NodeJS y Mongo Atlas, cuando quiero utilizar dentro de mis rutas las funcionalidades de "body-parser" no funciona.

es decir: no se guarda la información que yo genero a partir de Postman.

POST dentro de http://localhost:300/quotes/new

```
{
    "content": "esto es una nueva anotacion",
    "author": "Juan robles"
}
```

Código dentro de la ruta localhos:3000/quotes/new

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const quote = require('../models/quotes');

router.post('/new', async (req, res) => {
    const newQuote = new quote(req.body)
    const savedQuote = await newQuote.save();
    res.json(savedQuote);
});
```

Código dentro de mi carpeta models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const quoteSchema = new Schema({
    content: String,
    author: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('quote', quoteSchema);
```

Datos que se guardan en Mongo Atlas y devolución de Postman

```
{
    "_id": "609062b981492a2e045f2237",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique:

```
router.post('/new', async (req, res) => {
    const {content, author} = req.body
    const savingQuote = new quote({ content, author})//ES6: Abreviaturas
    const newQuote = await savingQuote.save() //.catch(err => err);
    res.json(newQuote);
});
```

Debe especificar la colección al momento de guardar un modelo (`quoteSchema`). Usando desestructuración extrae los datos del request, crea su instancia y guarda.

> El metodo save() es asíncrono, podría ser útil para usted.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias @mafu por la ayuda, fue el primer escalon para solucionar mi problema, ademas de eso yo tenia un error mas en mi archivo app.js las lineas de codigo `app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` estaban debajo de la linea `app.use('/quotes', quotesRouter);` entonces no funcionaba por eso, ahora que las coloque arriba funciona correctamente como deberia.

Comment: Que bueno haber aportado, saludos!